# How can I to centered my location with mylocationoverlay?

Tags: android

I can take my location with myLocationOverlay easily, and I want to set as a center of my location, I tried  map controller:

```
MapController mc = myMap.getController();
mc.animateTo();
mc.setCenter(myLocOverlay.getMyLocation());
```

these code didnt work so I changed

```
p = new GeoPoint((int) (myLocOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6()), (int) (myLocOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6()));

mc.setCenter(p);
```

But there is no good news. I took null pointer exception then I assigned new location before myLocationOverlay() but its not working.. Thanks for advance..

Answer (score 2):

The animateTo can be used for this,

```
GeoPoint point = this.currentLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
if(point==null)
  return;
//center map on that geopoint
mc.animateTo(point);
```